# Why does the Visual Studio Designer delete code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Several times throughout the course of our current project, the visual studio designer has made modifications that resulted in losing code.  For example, event handlers wirings that were set up manually in the designer code were lost.  Does anyone know why this happens?

Edit: I understand that editing these files manually is not a good idea, but it has also happened with other event wirings set up through the designer.

Comment: You probably manipulated the form or designer GUI which would result in the designer code being regenerated. These files generally have a header text that warns about making manual changes to them for that very reason.

Comment: Because when you hand control of your code over to Microsoft (via an abstraction like the designer) their always code feels it knows better what your code should look like. My advice would be to do any designer manipulations you need to do (if you really need to do them) *before* you start setting up event handlers and the like, then *never touch the designer again* in your project.

Comment: @robusto ugh.  Dude, not only is that impractical, but its also pointless.  You just don't edit the code within designer-generated files.  Its that simple.  Usually the designer will even set up codebehind files for you.  Never touch the designer again?  Ya, that's practical.  Never touch designer generated files, more like.

Comment: @Robusto: I'm assuming that was a joke?

Comment: @280z28: Yes. I guess nobody got it. Sigh.

Comment: It's called, or used to be called 'hacking'. microsoft folks never told us what would happen once you've modified that file. I guess 'bad and unpredictable things' could be an answer. You've 'hacked it', I mean 'tried it' and now you know and most importantly you can warn others. Good job guys!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well for starters read the XML at the top of your designer.cs file.

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
```

Generally you shouldn't be modifying these files as they are auto-generated. It's probably the reason why there is a slight attempt to hide the code within a branch, underneath the main partial class.

I have on occasion found that the process has removed its own auto-generated code that I've had to merge back in. Most commonly it decides it's not going to instantiate custom user controls anymore, so when I start running I get a NullReferenceException.

Really the answer is to put the code somewhere else, like in the constructor before calling the InitializeComponent() method. If fellow developers aren't aware of this, then you should inform them and educate them, the fact that the files are .designer.cs should raise questions even to newer developers as to why the strange extension.

Comment: That comment _used_ to be there (VS2005). In later editions it is absent in most .Designer.cs files. You're suppose to know by now.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to modify it, but not everyone here does.

Comment: @Henk : The comment is still present in VS2008. Not sure about VS2010 though, although I can't see a reason they'd take it out.

Comment: @Shane : Seems like a classic problem of not reading properly though, maybe it just doesn't stand out enough. Honestly I recall a time where I was caught out by the same problem using Java back in my student days.

Comment: @shane: Just make the people who are modifying it be responsible for fixing it when it breaks.  Then fire them for incompetence.

Comment: @Chris : Although education works too. You would hope that they'd learn through their mistakes.

Comment: @Ian: fair enough.  I'm sure hitting them over the head with a bit of Pavlov might help as well.

Comment: It is not so much that all of a sudden you get an urge to modify the auto-generated code as much as you need to 'correct' something manually. It is more often a case when you're maintaining a legacy code. For instance, a project that started as .net 1.1 and now it's .net 4. In my case, I've got screwed by running resharper that decided to "fix" some redundant types. After saving, I've lost ALL events on the form. (VS 2010 + Resharper 5.1)

Comment: @Henk The comment is still there in VS2008 and VS2010.

Answer (score 5):

You guys aren't modifying generated code files, are you?  Like `MyForm.Designer.cs`?  This is why we were given `partial` classes.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is designer generated and more or less maintained code.  It is recommended that you **not** add or modify code in the designer partial class manually exactly because of the behavior you described (I think it even mentions this in the generated file itself).  If you need to wire up event handlers manually then do it in your custom code possibly the constructor of your control.

Comment: +1 for the "more or less maintained code". I've seen VS screw up it's own code several times (menu items disappear from the menu, but still exist, images get embedded x times etc.).

Comment: @Bobby yeah sometimes it's a nightmare, especially with the menu items.. thank god it asks you about undo operations because of the black magic it performs when it undoes designer actions.

Answer (score 0):

Write all necessary initialization code only in your own .cs file, you have number of places to do this, like form constructor and form Load event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the designer code into user maintained code classes defeats the benefits of being able to modify the user interface. Perhaps this might be something you would want to do if the program never needs to be modified again, but if that is the case... where is the benefit as well?

This issue of the designer class losing lines of code has existed since Visual Studio was initially released and has caused me countless nightmares because the loss occurred perhaps weeks before, when the program was previously modified.

I can't prove it but it seems obvious that something in Microsoft's code generator is failing and there isn't any alerts to tell you it crashed.  So, Microsoft... fix what is crashing or at least, tell us about it when it happens.